# split a multi-line string in C

Tags: c, string, split, multilinestring

how can I split a multi-line string in const char* array.?

Here is the input string.

```
const char* str = "122.123,-38.789"
                  "122.123,-39.78";
```

I need to get two string from this.

```
str1 = "122.123,-38.789";

str2 = "122.123,-39.78";
```

output of

```
printf("string='%s'", str)

string='122.123,-38.789122.123,-39.78'
```

What should be done to split this string ?

Comment: There's no way to do this if you don't separate the strings somehow with a delimiter character or something. The way you're doing it, both strings are being merged into one, and because there's no delimiter character, there's also no way back.

Comment: Do you have control over `str`'s declaration?  Could you add a newline or other delimiter at the end?  `"122.123,-38.789\n"`, e.g.

Comment: @BrianCain, no i can't modify str. it is set by user. I guess the input must be considered invalid.

Comment: Something is afoul here.  Is it set by user or is it `const char*`?  Can you post something closer to the real code?

Answer (score 5):

Use an array of char *

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char* str[] = { "122.123,-38.789" ,  "122.123,-39.78" };

int main(){
  printf("%s\n%s\n",str[0],str[1] );
  return 0;
}
```

---

## How the compiler understood your code:

The C pre-processor concats  strings placed together,

```
const char* str = "122.123,-38.789"
                  "122.123,-39.78";
```

The linebreak between the strings is parsed as a blank, treated the same as a space or a tab. So it's equivalent to:

```
const char* str = "122.123,-38.789" "122.123,-39.78";
```

which the preprocessor converts to

```
const char* str = "122.123,-38.789122.123,-39.78";
```